# c# get object's 2d plot points from 3d position, unit vectors, and dimensions

Tags: c#, 3d, cad

I have xml data which is output from a 3D CAD system.
I need to take the xml data and build 2d plot points from it.
In a nutshell, given 3d position, unit vectors, and dimensions of the object I need to generate 2d plot points from a flat plane, in my case from the elevation "front" view as well as the bottom view.

I am looking for help or pointing me in the right direction for how to take the 3d global position values, unit vectors, and shape dimensions and generate 2d plot points for the shape, rectangles, polygons, etc.

Here is an explanation of my entire scenario for a better understanding of the practical application of it but not my intention to ask all of you to do my work for me just hoping for some direction.

The 3d CAD platform is being used to design the constructive framing of houses.
[image: 3d house framing]

Wall framing layout for a wall with 9 studs in it.

[image]

Every piece of the framing is designed as a part.
Each part is represented by the following xml inside of the framing container, in this case a wall panel:

In this example we have a piece of wood (a standard 2x4)
So, I need to build 2d points from this somehow, which represent the elevation view of the 2x4 stud standing vertically in a wall.

[image]

```
    <panel item_id="1E1" use="WALLPANEL" type="7" quantity="1" flength="120" fheight="97.1" fthick="3.5" length="120" height="97.1" thick="3.5">
    <position>
        <x x="1.000000000000" y="0.000000000000" z="0.000000000000" />
        <y x="0.000000000000" y="0.000000000000" z="1.000000000000" />
        <z x="0.000000000000" y="-1.000000000000" z="0.000000000000" />
        <p x="60.000000000000" y="-1.750000000000" z="0.000000000000" />
    </position>
    <struct type="wall" use="EXT">
        <route>
            <line type="line">
                <start x="60.000000000000" y="0.000000000000" z="-1.750000000000" />
                <end x="-60.000000000000" y="0.000000000000" z="-1.750000000000" />
            </line>
        </route>
        <layer order="0" use="FRAMING" mater="FRAME-4">
            <top_pleq a="0.000000000000" b="0.000000000000" c="1.000000000000" d="0.000000000000" />
            <bottom_pleq a="0.000000000000" b="0.000000000000" c="-1.000000000000" d="-3.500000000000" />
            <part type="piece" item_id="A" use="STUD" sect_code="2x4 S" nom_width="  1.5000" nom_height="  3.5000" mater="LUMBER" shape="RECT" length="92.625000">
                <position>
                    <x x="1.000000000000" y="0.000000000000" z="0.000000000000" />
                    <y x="0.000000000000" y="0.000000000000" z="1.000000000000" />
                    <z x="0.000000000000" y="-1.000000000000" z="0.000000000000" />
                    <p x="52.000000000000" y="94.125000000000" z="-1.750000000000" />
                </position>
```

My 2d result would be an array of 2d points representing the 2x4 piece.

```
   struct point2D {
      float x {get;set;}
      float y {get;set;
  }
  point2D[] points2d = ......etc.
```

And, the values for the example piece would be:

112,1.5
112,95.75
113.5,95.75
113.5, 1.5

Thank you everyone for reading this and for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to project all 3D points on the desired plane using [orthogonal projection](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/projections.html). The result will not be clear because to do this right you need a [Hidden Line Removal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-line_removal) algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will look into your suggestions.